# I want to run a query and display the result in Spring boot App, but some error is coming i don't know how to make it right

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

```
package demo;
import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringMySqlApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMySqlApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        
        String sql = "select EmpID, EmpName, EmpAge, EmpDept FROM employees";

        ArrayList<Employee> el = 

                jdbcTemplate.query(sql,ResultSetExtractor<ArrayList<Employee>>());
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token
```

I created a employee list. I want to run a query using jdbcTemplate. I was expecting to get a list having employee info.

Comment: If my answer helps request you to please accept the answer so that it helps others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run same code in my local and got to know that there are compilation errors in run() method. Please refactor your run() method like this and try again.

**Solution1 (*Without Lambda function*)**

```
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        String sql = "select EmpID, EmpName, EmpAge, EmpDept FROM employees";
        List<Employee> el =
                jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<List<Employee>>(){
                    @Override
                    public List<Employee> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                        List<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();
                        while(rs.next()){
                            Employee e=new Employee();
                            e.setEmpId(rs.getInt(1));
                            e.setEmpName(rs.getString(2));
                            e.setEmpAge(rs.getInt(3));
                            e.setEmpDept(rs.getString(4));
                            list.add(e);
                        }
                        return list;
                    }
                });
    }
```

**Solution2 (*With Lambda function*)**

```
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        String sql = "select EmpID, EmpName, EmpAge, EmpDept FROM employees";
        List<Employee> el =
                jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rs -> {
                    List<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();
                    while(rs.next()){
                        Employee e=new Employee();
                        e.setEmpId(rs.getInt(1));
                        e.setEmpName(rs.getString(2));
                        e.setEmpAge(rs.getInt(3));
                        e.setEmpDept(rs.getString(4));
                        list.add(e);
                    }
                    return list;
                });
    }
```